# Return to method, which contains postDelayed

Tags: android, methods, return

I just created boolean method, which should at the end return some boolean variable...
BUT I want to return it 1 second later (some operations is making in app)
This code but don't work...
What should I do?

```
private boolean variable;
public boolean Method(String device) {
    //some code here

    //then postdelayed
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //variable is set in other part of app
            return variable;
        }
    }, 1000);

}
```

Comment: What happens exactly? What do you mean by "variable is set in other part of app"..? Why don't you use the EventBus for thing kind of thing?

Comment: @Vucko the variable, which I want to return i defined in same code upper...  When method starts, it first send variable "device"(input) and then there is some scanning up in the code and then i want to return this variable which is changed up in the code... (sorry for my english)

Comment: I don't see anything incorrect. This will work fine. There must be a problem when setting the variable itself in the other part of the app.

Comment: @HusseinElFeky What he wants isn't actually possible, short of a sleep.  Its definitely not correct-  you can't return a value from a void function, and you can't return on a delay

Comment: @HusseinElFeky It says on return : "Cannot return a value from a method with void result type" and on last bracket it says: "missing return statement"

Comment: @GabeSechan Oh yes, I didn't notice that void. Definitely you are correct. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.  You need to rearchitecture what you're doing.  The only way to delay a return is to hold up the UI thread, which is not the right way to do anything ever.  What you need to do is make any code that needs the return value execute in the postDelayed Runnable.  What you want to do will never work.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out little bit differently ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can move that handler to the part where you want to call and get that boolean variable, like:

```
private String device;
private boolean variable;

public void doSomething() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (getBoolean(device)) {
                // Do something.
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
}

public boolean getBoolean(String device) {
    // Some code...
    return variable;
}
```